# Importing files with similar names from different folders in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've got two different files with same name for which I'm writing unitests. The file structure is as follows:

```
Proj\
 Task\
  Folder1\
   needtotest.py
  Folder2\
   needtotest.py
```

My test file's folder structure: `Proj\test\test.py`

And in my setup config my PYTHONPATH is set as :
`PYTHONPATH=Proj\Task\Folder2\needtotest.py Proj\Task\Folder1\needtotest.py`

whenever I'm importing needtotest module in test.py it picks up the one from Folder2(Which makes sense because of my pythonpath). But I can't change my PYTHONPATH or my file names due to some other issue. Is there a way to import needtotest.py from Folder1?

I've tried `sys.append`  it doesn't work. Another method I tried was:
`import Proj.Task.Folder2.needtotest` also fails due to syntactical error.

```
E  from Proj.Task.Folder2.needtotest import lambda_handler
E              ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: _Another method I tried was: `import Proj.Task.Folder2.needtotest` that also fails due to syntactical error_ Show us the error.

Comment: `E       from Proj.Task.Folder2.needtotest import foo

E                         ^

E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Why is there a capital E at the end of the import statement?  That is indeed an error.

Comment: The E should be in the next line.

Comment: Don't make us guess what the actual code is.  Please update the question to include the full code and the full error traceback message.

Comment: the code is just a simple test function the main question is importing the module, it doesn't even reach the code part. It basically imports the wrong module from the different folder

Comment: `from Proj.Task.Folder2.needtotest import lambda_handler` is not, by itself, a syntax error.  I assume that the actual error is on one of the previous lines of code in that module, which is why I asked to see the full code.

Answer (score 0):

the second options to import the similar file name from different folder is much easier. However, it relies on the current directory you are working on as well. Most of the time, syntactical error always occur when we specify the path that did not be seen by your current workspace.

For example, here is your directories

```
Proj\
 Task\
  Folder1\
   needtotest.py
  Folder2\
   needtotest.py
```

To checking where you currently are, you can simply do in your terminal:

```
pwd
```

Let's say that it output as `Proj/Task`. it means that you are currently at the Task folder where it saw both Folder1 and Folder2. To import the files with the same name, you can simply do as follows:

```py
# first way
from Folder1 import needtotest as test1
from Folder2 import needtotest as test2

# to utilize function from Folder1 (the test case you've written)
test1.your_test_function()

# to utilize function from Folder2 (the test case you've written)
test2.your_test_function()
```

In case it is still cause syntactical error, you may reconsider the current working directory and changing you working directory to the place where you related to access the file.

Comment: Doesn't work, I can't make changes to my working directory